# Downloading software

Tags: software-installation

I would like to specify a specific location (onto and external hard drive) for software to be placed when downloading it. How would I do this? Thank you!

Comment: What method are you using to download? Are you using firefox, wget, aria2, chromium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- aria2

  ```
  aria2c --dir=<your_target_folder> URL
  ```
- wget

  ```
  wget --directory-prefix=<your_target_folder> URL
  ```
- curl

  ```
  curl -o <your_target_folder>/<your_target_file> URL
  ```
- Chrome/Chromium

  - Open the URL `chrome://settings/`
  - Click "Advanced settings"
  - Scroll down until you see the entry "Downloads" and change it to whatever you want.
- Firefox

  - Open the URL `about:preferences#general`
  - Scroll down until you see the entry "Downloads" (and change)

Comment: What about downloading software from software manager? Basically I have no room left on the solid state that my operating system is on. So any software I download has to be placed into the external drive. And thank you for your previous reply!

Comment: You can't specify a download target for any type of software managers in Linux. At least not without putting the whole system upside down

Comment: Search for a guide to remove unnecessary files on AskUbuntu.